# $watch triggers in all directives of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a "scrolling-picker" custom directive that is repeated n times. I have placed a watch function inside the link.

directive

```
app.directive('ngPicker', function($interval, $timeout, $window){
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    replace : true,
    templateUrl : 'partials/ng-picker-template.html',
    scope : { items : '=', params : '=', selectedValue : '=', unit : '@', id : '@'},
    link: function($scope, elem, attrs){
         $scope.$watch("selectedValue", function(newValue, oldValue){               
            console.log($scope.selectedValue);
            //do something              
         });
```

html

```
<div ng-repeat="pick in pickers">
    <ng-picker items="allItems" params="spinParams"
       selected-value="pick.value" 
       c-model="{{currentCompartment.subCompartments[inputField].quantity.feet}}"
       unit="{{wheelOptions.mainUnit}}">
    </ng-picker>
```

Now if I change the value in parent controller the watch is triggered in all directives. But I need to watch only in the one directive where it corresponds.

Comment: How are you changing the parent value? If you correctly change only the value that corresponds to the individual picker, it should not trigger them all.

Comment: That is not in my part of coding. I'm trying to build this as a component which can be used anywhere. Anything can I do from my part?

Comment: Code is working fine in this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/a2zn2S7Qq6AikZpW4DpE?p=preview
Changing one of the`pick` items only triggers the relevant watcher, It should be noted that all watchers are triggered initially.